# Put text and image on the same line

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to put text and an image on the same line but for one reason or another it's not working. The text is coming up fine but there is no sign of the image.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#DCDBDB" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="@string/quoteDevil"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight="0.00"`??. And the View order is wrong: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` takes up **all the available space**. Then, there's **no space left** for the ImageView. And you should also add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to the LinearLayout. Anyway, I'd get rid of the three and only leave the TextView, with a **compound drawable** inside. For better performances, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to add orientation property to LinearLayout:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and change the width property from the inside elements from match_parent to wrap_content, if you put match_parent only show one element

Change

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

For

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Example

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI: There is a "tip" for displaying an image within a `TextView`.

In fact, any images stored in the `drawable` folders can actually be embedded within a `TextView` at several key locations in relation to the text using the `android:drawableRight` / `android:drawableLeft` and the `android:drawablePadding` property.

An example:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/my_contacts"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_add_group"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
/>
```

The result is:

[image: Image within TextView]

Source: [Link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-TextView)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to have two things in one row is to use TableRow

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/quoteDevil"
        android:textSize="21sp" />    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

but if you want to use LinearLayout you have to define orientation as horizontal

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quoteDevil"
        android:textSize="21sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/centra_crm" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```